# Can't connect to MySQL from C++

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, linux

From some application, I can't connect to a remote database server:

```
  MYSQL conn;  

  if(!mysql_init(&conn))
      std::wcout << "Error: can't create MySQL-descriptor" << endl;   

  if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,"ip","user","password","dbname",0,0,0))
       std::wcout << "Error: can't connect to MySQL server" << endl;     

  if(mysql_query(&conn, "SELECT VERSION()") != 0)
       std::wcout << "Error: can't execute SQL-query" << endl;
```

I opened port `3306` on the remote server:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
 iptables save
 iptables restart
```

Error:

> Failed to connect to database:Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'ip_..' (10060)

What could be the reason?

Comment: For supplementary information, better update the question (it is a little weird to comment your own question). Are you sure it is not a networking issue, for example, are you able to connect to this server from another application using the same credentials?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can connect from that machine?  I would install MySQL Workbench and make sure I can establish a connection before looking to my code.  You could also try using 3306 (or whatever your server is configured on) for the port instead of 0...  Yeah, I know the docs say 0 is okay, but I have a vague memory of that being a lie.

Comment: Has MySQL been told to listen to external interfaces, and not only local connections?

Comment: you'll have to make sure the user has permissions to connect from a remote host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should display result of [mysql_error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-error.html) after every failed test (following a successful `mysql_init`), e.g.:

```
 if(!mysql_real_connect(&conn,"ip","user","password","dbname",0,0,0))
     std::wcout << "Error: can't connect to MySQL server:"
                << mysql_error (&conn) << endl;
```

otherwise your user won't be able to understand what is happening to him.

You'll probably find out what is happening. If not, look into the documentation.